# CSS overflow character not pushing down <div>

Tags: css

I have a `<div>` called bigbox which contain a `<div>`called wrapper . The wrapper contain 2 `<div>` called textbox and checkbox. If the characters inside textbox overflow , it doesn't push the other wrapper below . How can I make the below wrapper go down ?

here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/WA63P/

[image]

```
 <html>
 <head>
<title>Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">


.bigbox  {
    background-color: #F5E49C;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0 5px;
    width:280px;
    height:500px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;content: "";display: block;clear: both;
}



.box   {

    background-color: #272822;
    color: #9C5A3C;
    height:100px;
    width:260px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative; top:10px;
}   
.textbox
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #272822;
    height:100px;
    width:160px;float:left;text-align: left

}   
.checkbox
{
background-color: #FFFFFF;
height:50px;
width:50px;
float:right;
d
}   

</style>



 <div class="bigbox">

 <div class="box"> 
  <div class="textbox">background background background background background background background background background background background background background background background background background background background background background background </div>
  <div class="checkbox"> </div>
  </div>


 <div class="box"> 
  <div class="textbox"> </div>
  <div class="checkbox"> </div>
  </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.bigbox  {
    background-color: #F5E49C;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0 5px;
    width:280px;
    height:500px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;content: "";display: block;
}

.box   {
    background-color: #272822;
    color: #9C5A3C;
    width:260px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative; top:10px;
}   
.textbox
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #272822;
    min-height:100px;
    width:160px;
    text-align: left;
}   
.checkbox
{
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width:50px;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
right:0px;
height:50px;
}
```

Remove the `float:left` in your `.textbox` to make it static, as static blocks automatically push the other static blocks down. Also remove the `height` to avoid setting a fixed height and allow it height to shrink/wrap automatically.

To position the checkbox as in your picture, you could use `position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px;`

Check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WA63P/4/)

Comment: And where's the `checkbox`?

Comment: @zeroflagL: sorry, forgot about the checkbox, see updated demo